# Difference between stored procedure and function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know the main differences between stored procedure and function, but one difference is that functions can be called from within a stored procedure, but a stored procedure can not be called from within a function.

My question is why can we not call a stored procedure from within a function?

Comment: Please see this link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/1b9fc3dd-cdb2-4c4e-8142-c4f1826e1b9f/why-we-dont-exucete-store-procedure-in-a-user-defined-function?forum=transactsql

Answer (score 4):

Stored procedures can change data, thus the result of a function calling a stored procedure can be undeterministic. For instance, if you write a stored procedure which sets users to be inactive if they did not log in for a while and you write a function which counts inactive users, but calls the stored procedure before that, then the expected result of the function will be changed while it is being executed.

I do not agree with this approach either, but this is how it works. Note that procedures can have out parameters, which means that you can use them as functions. So, if you want to call p1 from f1, then modify f1 to be a stored procedure having out parameter(s).

Answer (score 3):

Functions cannot do any changes in database but can read them.

Stored procedures can do anything and everything with databases.

You cannot execute a stored procedure from a function. But you can execute a function inside a Stored Procedure.

You can execute an extended stored procedure from a function.(though it is not a good practice).